# Implementing prerender SPA plugin to vue2js application

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli, prerender

I'm trying to implement very popular [prerender SPA plugin](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin#what-is-prerendering).

Documentation say to add module to **webpack.config.js** but I don't have such file I have **webpack.base.conf.js**, **webpack.dev.conf.js** and **webpack.prod.conf.js**.

In first there is no plugins array but it is in last two. So I injected in them:

```
new PrerenderSPAPlugin({
    // Required - The path to the webpack-outputted app to prerender.
    staticDir: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    // Required - Routes to render.
    routes: [ '/' ],
})
```

to plugins array and I required it at the top of file. Then I run in command line

```
> npm run build
> cd dist
> live-server
```

`npm run build` created dist folder in root directory and now after I added plugin it additionaly add dist directory in config directory where the webpack.conf files are located. In this new dist folder inside config directory is index.html file which is basically empty html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Not Found</pre>


</body></html>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake in root component which is App.vue. I didn't have `id="app"` to my root div.

Comment: I have the same problem, except I have my id="app" properly where it belongs, so I am just responding to see if I can revive the thread

Comment: You should create another question.